# Need continuous loop command

Tags: powershell

I have a script I need to loop continuously with time interval 1 minute.

I am using the script is used for intimate the battery percentage to the user

```
$results=(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Battery).EstimatedChargeRemaining

if ($results -gt 20)
{

$ButtonType = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information
$MessageBody = "Remove the charger. Your battery percentage $results"
$MessageTitle = "Laptop Battery Backup status"
$Result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)

}
elseif ($results -lt 10) {

$ButtonType = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning
$MessageBody = "Connect the charger. Your battery percentage $results"
$MessageTitle = "Laptop Battery Backup status"
$Result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)

}
```

Comment: Look up Start-Sleep cmdlet.

Comment: Put the whole code inside a `while ($true) {..}` endless loop and as [conPryz commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952937/need-continuous-loop-command#comment127144745_71952937) add `Start-Sleep -Seconds 60` as the last line in that loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This intrigued me so I played around and made some changes you might want.

The code below will not prompt you to disconnect the charger if it is not connected and will not prompt you to connect the charger if it is connected when the appropriate conditions are met.

I've set the full charge and low charge percentages in variables at the top of the script to make them easy to locate and change and I also set them to keep the battery between 20-80% the recommended range for longevity of Lithium-Ion batteries as I understand it.

Also the time between messages set to 3 minutes as batteries shouldn't drain fast enough that they need to be checked every minute, even 3 minutes may be too often.

Lastly, I provided an escape incase you want to turn the program off with the cancel button.

```
$FullChgPct = 78
$NeedChgPct = 22

$MessageTitle = "Laptop Battery Backup status"
$Result       = "OK"
$ButtonType   =
   [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OKCancel

While ($Result -eq "OK") {

  $Battery=Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Battery
  $ChgPct = $Battery.EstimatedChargeRemaining
  $Mains  = $Battery.Status        
  
  if ($ChgPct -gt $FullChgPct -and
      $Mains  -eq 2)   {
  
  $MessageIcon = 
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information
  $MessageBody = 
     "Remove the charger. Your battery percentage $ChgPct"
  $Result = 
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
     $MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
  
  }

  If ($ChgPct -lt $NeedChgPct -and
      $Mains  -eq 1) {
  
  $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning
  $MessageBody = 
     "Connect the charger. Your battery percentage $ChgPct"
  $Result = 
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
     $MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
  
  }

  # Notify user every 3 Minutes
  If ($Result -eq "OK") { Start-Sleep -Seconds 300 }
  
} #End While
```